# PHP best practice getting a value of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, matrix

I'd like to know if there's something like a best practice to get a single value of a 2d array in php. Like shown in the image below, the user will be able to enter a number for the column and a number for the row so he will get the result as return. For example: input = 5 and 7, he will get 58 as return.

What's the best practice to realize something like that in PHP?

[image: Matrix]

Comment: normally we use `$arr_var[5][7]`

Comment: what do you mean best practice? very vague, just use it as your indices, thats about it.

Comment: `$matrix[$row][$column]` – what part of that do you need to optimise?

Comment: Actually, for this particular matrix, the optimum would be `$row * 10 + $col + 1`, no "matrix" needed. :P

Comment: i'm sorry! by best practice i meant would it be better to just declare an array with the values or would you add this into a database. The values might change in future and the size of the matrix might extend.

Comment: That will depend a lot on the use case and what that matrix represents. Again, in this specific example the most sensible thing is to use the simple formula above. Your actual best solution may be something entirely different, we just can't tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? PHP 5.4.

```
    $arr = [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
        [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
        [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
        [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
        [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
        [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
        [91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
    ];
    // input 5 & 7, res is 58.
    $res = $arr[5][7];
```

Comment: well it seems like this is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: `$arr = array_chunk(range(1, 100), 10);` I hope you didn't type all that by hand. :)

Comment: I think the questioner‘s matrix is disorderly. And your code is amazing.

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing behind that. Just take value from the proper indices.
It's nothing to optimize. You might only make it more complex.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

// previous page
// $_POST['array'] = $2darray;

$numarray = $_POST['array'];
$col = $_POST['col'];
$row = $_POST['rows'];

echo $numarray[$row][$col];

?>
```